# MySQL - clarification on table partition / subpartition

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, database-partitioning

I've a table with around 300 millions records in it (only for 60 days). The table structure is quite simple .. 
It has 12 columns, which 4 of them are Indexed:

```
LogTime - DateTime
RegionID - Integer
ProvinceID - Integer
CityID - Integer
```

There is also a Unique Index:

```
UNIQUE INDEX UI_IDX (`LogTime`, `RegionID`, `ProvinceID`, `CityID`);
```

The rest of fields are just values that mostly being fetched by query results.

The database-server is already tuned with good condition (~12GB for buffer-space and etc)

Well, For speeding up the queries I decided to partition the table on `LogTime` field. I achieved this goal by partitioning the table with `PARTITION BY RANGE`. Now I've 365 partitions for the table (1 partition for 1 day , 5 millions records for each partition).

The thing is we're not satisfied with query performance, and I was looking for a way to break-down the partitions to smaller pieces .. lets say partition a table on LogTime and RegionID ... I'm not sure if it is applicable in Sub-partition ...

Comment: Partitioning does not intrinsically provide any performance.  Please show us the actual queries that you need better performance on.  The index(es) and partitioning has to be based on the queries.

Comment: Do not use more than about 50 partitions; things slow down.  More on partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: Hey Rick, and thanks for response. This is one of my sample queries which take minutes to feedback the result: `select b.CityName, a.val1, a.val2 from DataRepo a left join City b on a.CityID = b.CityID where (a.LogTime >= '2015-08-01 00:00:00' and a.LogTime <= '2015-08-05 00:00:00') and a.RegionID = 1 and a.ProvinceID = 14;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For

```
select  b.CityName, a.val1, a.val2
    from  DataRepo a
    left join  City b on a.CityID = b.CityID
    where  (a.LogTime >= '2015-08-01 00:00:00'
       and  a.LogTime <= '2015-08-05 00:00:00' )
      and  a.RegionID = 1
      and  a.ProvinceID = 14;
```

The optimal index is

```
INDEX(RegionID, ProvinceID, -- in either order
      LogTime)    -- last
```

No `PARTITIONing` will help speed up the query above what that index can deliver.

(Unrelated)
Did you deliberately want to check 4 days plus one second?

I like this design pattern:

```
    where  (a.LogTime >= '2015-08-01'
       and  a.LogTime <  '2015-08-01' + INTERVAL 4 DAY )
```

Oh...  This index would be even faster, because it is "covering":

```
INDEX(RegionID, ProvinceID, -- in either order
      LogTime,    -- range
      CityID)     -- the rest of the fields used in the SELECT
```

With that, the query will be performed entirely (aside from the `JOIN`) in the index, without touching the data.  `EXPLAIN` will say "Using index".

(Another aside)  Is Region a subset of Province?  Or vice versa?  If so, you don't need both columns in the Fact table, do you?  (Shrinking the Fact table is another technique for improving performance, since you are doubtless I/O-bound.)

(More)  Is Province `INT`?  That's 4 bytes.  If there are under 255 Provinces, use `TINYINT UNSIGNED`, which is only 1 byte.  That will save nearly 1GB in the table, plus another GB in the index I proposed.

Comment: one thing I could confirm now is that you're probably right about using `TINYINT` instead of `INT`, I'll take care of that. I've one question about your proposed optimal index .. as you see in my first post I've already defined UNIQUE INDEX for same fields .. I see no difference in there .. could you please explain the difference here ? thank you.

Comment: Your `UNIQUE` key _starts_ with `LogTime`.  The last column that is useful is a range column.  That is yours will filter _only_ on LogTime, having to scan lots of rows to also filter on Province and Region.  My index makes use of all 3 columns.  Yours could be turned into mine by rearranging.

Comment: I would like to see the entire `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there may be other things to critique.  With **300M** rows, lots of details become very important.  (With 300 rows, no details matter much.)

Comment: Got it :) Thank you so much for your time. allow me to modify required fields/indexes based on your reply. I'll check the result with you later. ps: it is 4am here ;)

Comment: India?  An `ALTER` will take a loooong time, do all the changes at the same time.  And consider using `pt-online-schema-change`.

Comment: Iran actually :) thank you Rick I did some changes on table based on your general ideas ... the query speed has been improved greatly since then ;)